# My script is not displaying links properly

Tags: php, html, zip, archive, unzip

It's gonna be hard for me to explain the whole situation, but I'll try...

I made a script for my image host that unZips a Zip package with images in it to a certain location, renames the files to a random file name and outputs multiple links to the images. The last part is not working properly! I am unable to output multiple links to the images - It simply outputs one link to the image (the first one) and the rest is in the uploaded folder, but not listed as a link.

Same goes with generating a thumbnail for the just renamed images. Only one thumbnail is generated for the first image, and the rest of the images if being ignored.

This is how my code looks like:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/imgit.class.php');
$IMGit = new imgit();

/**
* @ignore
*/
if (!defined('IN_IMGIT'))
{
    exit;
}

$IMGit->error_report(true);
$IMGit->disable(false);
$IMGit->ieNote(true);

if (isset($_POST['zipsent']) || $_POST['zipsent'] == true && isset($_FILES['archive']))
{   
    if ($_FILES['archive']['size'] <= MAX_ZIPSIZE)
    {
        // Main variables
        $key        = $IMGit->random_key(10);
        $move_zip   = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name'], ZIP_PATH . $key . $_FILES['archive']['name']); 
        $zip        = ZIP_PATH . $key . $_FILES['archive']['name'];
        $extension  = substr($zip, -3);
        $filename   = $IMGit->zipContent($zip); // array
        $url        = str_replace('www.', '', $IMGit->generate_site_url());

        // ZIP limit is 100 images  
        if (sizeof($filename) <= 100)
        {
            // Only ZIP archives
            if ($extension == 'zip')
            {   
                if ($filename)
                {
                    foreach($filename as $key => $value)
                    {
                        // Get extension
                        $image_extension = substr($value, -3);
                        $image_extension = (strtoupper($image_extension)) ? strtolower($image_extension) : $image_extension;
                        $image_extRule   = $image_extension == JPG || $image_extension == JPEG || $image_extension == GIF || $image_extension == PNG || 
                                           $image_extension == BMP || $image_extension == ICO;

                        if ($image_extRule)
                        {
                            // Set variables and do some processing
                            $unZip       = $IMGit->unZip($zip, IMAGES_PATH);
                            $url         = str_replace('www.', '', $IMGit->generate_site_url());
                            $image_name  = $IMGit->random_key(7) . $value;
                            $image_name  = (strpos($image_name, ' ') !== false) ? str_replace(' ', '', $image_name) : $image_name;

                            if (file_exists(IMAGES_PATH . $filename[$key]))
                            {
                                // Rename extracted files
                                $rename = rename(IMAGES_PATH . $filename[$key], IMAGES_PATH . $image_name);

                                if ($rename && file_exists($zip) && sizeof($image_name))
                                {
                                    // Delete ZIP
                                    unlink($zip);   

                                    // Set URL variables
                                    $image_urls = $url . IMAGES_PATH . $image_name; 
                                    $image      = IMAGES_PATH . $image_name;    

                                    // Generate a thumbnail
                                    $IMGit->generate_thumbnail($image_urls, $image_name, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, true, 'file', false, false, THUMBS_PATH);
                                    $thumb_urls = $url . THUMBS_PATH . $image_name;

                                    $filename[] = array('direct' => $image_urls, 'thumb' => $thumb_urls);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else 
{
    header('Location: index.php');  
}

include('includes/header.php');
{
    if      ($_FILES['archive']['size'] > MAX_ZIPSIZE) { echo '<span id="home-info">The ZIP archive is bigger than 100 MB.</span>'; }
    else if ($extension != 'zip') { echo '<span id="home-info">Only ZIP archives are upload ready.</span>'; }
    else if (sizeof($filename) > 100) { echo '<span id="home-info">The number of the images inside the archive was more than 100.</span>'; }
    else if (!$image_extRule) { echo '<span id="home-info">The extensions inside the ZIP did not match our allowed extension list.</span>'; unlink($zip); } // unlink zip if failed
    else    { echo '<span id="home-info">Image(s) was/were successfully uploaded!</span>'; }
}
?>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<a href="index.php"><img src="css/images/site-logo.jpg" id="logo" /></a>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>

<div id="box">
<?php   
    global $filename, $image_urls, $thumb_urls;

    echo '<br />';
    echo '<div id="links">';
    echo '<table>';

    echo LINKS_DIRECT;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filename); $i++) { echo $filename[$i]['direct'] . "\n"; }
    echo LINKS_CLOSE;

    echo LINKS_THUMB;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filename); $i++) { echo $filename[$i]['thumb'] . "\n"; }
    echo LINKS_CLOSE;

    echo LINKS_BBCODE;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filename); $i++) { echo '[IMG]' . $filename[$i]['direct'] . '[/IMG]' . "\n"; } 
    echo LINKS_CLOSE;

    echo LINKS_HTML;
    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($filename); $i++) { echo '<a href="' . $filename[$i]['direct'] . '"><img src="' . $filename[$i]['thumb'] . '" /></a>' . "\n"; }
    echo LINKS_CLOSE;

    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<input type="reset" id="resetbtn-remote" class="button-sub" value="&laquo; Upload more" />';
    echo '<br />';
    echo '</div>';
?>
</div>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess the problem is inside the foreach loop (it was a for loop a few days ago, but faced the same problems), but I can't seem to fix it. I'll reexplain in a short version:

- I upload a Zip archive
- Script unZips the archive
- Script renames the extracted files
- Thumbnail must be generated for all images that were in the Zip (fails)
- Multiple links should be outputted matching every image the was in the Zip (fails)

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem just by removing the following code part:

```
file_exists($zip)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are re-using a variable ($filename) for two different purposes.  At the top, add a line like this:

```
$file_list = array();
```

Later in the code, where you do this:

```
$filename[] = array('direct' => $image_urls, 'thumb' => $thumb_urls);
```

... change it to this:

```
$file_list[] = array('direct' => $image_urls, 'thumb' => $thumb_urls);
```

Later in your code where you loop, use `foreach` instead:

```
echo LINKS_DIRECT;
foreach ($file_list as $this_file)
    echo $this_file['direct'] . "\n";
echo LINKS_CLOSE;

echo LINKS_THUMB;
foreach ($file_list as $this_file)
    echo $this_file['thumb'] . "\n";
echo LINKS_CLOSE;

echo LINKS_BBCODE;
foreach ($file_list as $this_file)
    echo '[IMG]' . $this_file['direct'] . '[/IMG]' . "\n";
echo LINKS_CLOSE;

echo LINKS_HTML;
foreach ($file_list as $this_file)
    echo '<a href="' . $this_file['direct'] . '"><img src="' . $this_file['thumb'] . '" /></a>' . "\n";
echo LINKS_CLOSE;
```

You've got a lot of other odd things going on in there, like using constants for HTML fragments. I think you should take another look at your process there and eliminate some of the unnecessary steps and variables. I see several `global` keywords used... none appear to be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Chris. Unfortunately, this did not fix my problem. As I said in the first post, neither the thumbnails are being generated for the images. Means the problem is somewhere around where the renaming happens. But your answer was very useful, because I assume that once the problem gets fixed, the links are going to be displayed using the form you explained. - Now please guys, help me find where that problem is.

Comment: I have found the problem, but I did not fix it as I don't know how. Let me explain. See the part of the code which says `sizeof($image_name)`. I changed it to `sizeof($image_name) > 1` and nothing is now being outputted - means $image_name is generating just one name.